# Camera is not saving after taking image

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, kotlin-android-extensions

Camera is not saving after taking image in Redmi 1s. **This works great in samsung j5-2016**. I am trying to take picture and upload on server. Before uploading i am compressing image, so i need filename and file path. How I get **fileName** is displays in activity result method.

**Camera Intent**

```
val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 102)
                        }
```

In samsung phone this saves picture, thus i am able to get file from uri. But in redmi 1s i am not able to get uri. I think it seems like redmi 1s not saving taken picture, therefore i am not able to get file.
**OnActivityResult in fragments displays as:**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 102) && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val uri = data.data

                val mimeType = activity.contentResolver.getType(uri)
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    val path = getPath(uri)
                    if (path == null) {
                        fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uri.toString())
                    } else {
                        val file = File(path)
                        fileName = file.getName()
                    }
                } else {
                    val returnUri = data.getData()
                    val returnCursor = activity.contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
                    val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                    val sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                    returnCursor.moveToFirst()
                    fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
                    val size = Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex));
                }
}
    }
```

I am getting **error** in

```
val mimeType = activity.contentResolver.getType(uri)
```

**ErrorLog**

```
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireExistingProvider(ContentResolver.java:1405)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.getType(ContentResolver.java:304)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at in.motiontech.wave.fragment.ReviewOrderFragment.onActivityResult(ReviewOrderFragment.kt:396)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5434)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-23 17:17:52.039 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-23 17:17:52.049 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
08-23 17:17:52.049 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 17:17:52.049 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 17:17:52.049 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-23 17:17:52.049 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
08-23 17:17:52.049 12008-12008/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help me if I am doing anything wrong please suggest other option.

I have also looked some Stackoverflow posts but not able to find answer :

[Camera Intent not saving photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720383/camera-intent-not-saving-photo)

[Camera is not saving after taking picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224011/camera-is-not-saving-after-taking-picture)

[Can not save camera's captured photo in application's "files" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618074/can-not-save-cameras-captured-photo-in-applications-files-folder)

**Edit**
I have also tried following for **Camera Intent**

```
val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                        val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                        var output = File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpeg")
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output)
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 102)
                        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Camera is not saving after taking image in Redmi 1s.

It will not "save" anything with most camera apps. You specifically set up your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` to not save a photo anywhere.

> This works great in samsung j5-2016

Only because you are using a buggy camera app on that device.

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return a `Uri`. It it supposed to do one of two things:

1. If you include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, the camera app is supposed to save a full-resolution photo to the `Uri` that you provide in that extra
2. Otherwise, you get a `Bitmap` back via `getParcelableExtra("data")` on the returned `Intent`

Since you do not have `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you should not expect a full-resolution photo to be saved anywhere.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/FileProvider) shows how to use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @LalitJadav: Did you adjust your `onActivityResult()` to look in the location that you supplied to `EXTRA_OUTPUT`?

Comment: Does samsung default camera app is buggy? as you says Only because you are using a buggy camera app on that device

Comment: @LalitJadav: "I think It returns uri" -- not according to the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` documentation, and not according to the developers of many camera apps.

Comment: @LalitJadav: "Does samsung default camera app is buggy?" -- if it is returning a `Uri`, then it is not following the documented `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol, and therefore it has a bug.

Comment: what does data.data returns?

Comment: @LalitJadav: Its contents are undocumented. You should assume that it is `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152642/discussion-between-lalit-jadav-and-commonsware).

Comment: `Otherwise, you get a Bitmap back via getParcelableExtra("data") on the returned Intent`. Yes. But the Camera app will also have saved a full sized jpg in the DCIM directory.

Comment: @greenapps: Not necessarily. That is up to the camera app. There are hundreds of camera apps pre-installed across thousands of Android device models, and there are hundreds more on the Play Store and other app distribution channels.